# Cannot Read Property 'split' of Undefined in the below code

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**Why split property is undefined here? I fetched the products from my product api through axios, I received json data that have some properties(name,description,...)**

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
let substrings=[];
  useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/products/${props.match.params.id}`);
        setProduct(res.data);
     
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    getProduct();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  
  const substrings = product.description.split(".");

This is the json that we get from products/id
{"_id":"1","name":"Mangoes","image":"https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1Iq2F4fYxDi7HdX-IJcRuON-CbNuK-pxd","description":"This sweet and fresh mangoes make your day sweet","category":"Fruits","keywords":"fruits","price":120,"countInStock":0,"content":""}
```

**whereas it works fine here**

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
const [desc,setDesc]=useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(`/products/${props.match.params.id}`);
        setProduct(res.data);
        setDesc(res.data.description);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    getProduct();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  
  const substrings = desc.split(".");
```

Can anyone tell us why is it so?

Comment: In the first example, what is `product`? Is it initially a state value that is an empty string?

Comment: @Jayce444  please check the updated code. product is initially a state value with empty array

Comment: Ok so the problem is that in the first example `product` is initially an empty object, so `product.description` is undefined. So when you try to access `product.description.split`, you get the logical error of trying to access `.split` of something that's undefined. You may say that you execute an API request to fetch the product info and store it in state, but fetching that info (as well as setting state itself) are both asynchronous, so they get delayed until after the first render. So initially, when it tries to render, `product.description` is undefined

Comment: @jayce444 got it!!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think before the load product, the value of your product is null or {},
so when you use product.description the value will be undefined.
You can use:

```js
const substrings = (product?.description || '').split(".");
```

Comment: Yes, It's working fine!
But I could not understand the above line.

Comment: @Pikachu split just working with string, so if your value is not string you will get error.
the syntax ?. will return undefined if product is not object

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is the way you declared the `product` using `useState`. For the second part you declare the `description` directly so when you split it, it might be an empty string or whatever you declared it, but not undefined.

But for the first part, you declare just the `product` variable, without the `description` property. So before fetching, when you try to split `product.description`, it is undefined and becomes a value just after fetching.

In order to fix it you might declared the product like this:

`const [product, setProduct] = useState({ description: "" })` or just simply use `?` operator like this: `const substrings = product.description?.split(".");`

Also there might be a problem because you first declare `substrings` as an empty array and then you declare it again as a `const`.